# JAR from JFrog Artifactory downloading to the Gradle cache but not displaying in Project and External Dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, artifactory

My Java Gradle project is not resolving JARs to the **Project and External Dependencies**. However, I have checked the **Gradle cache** location(*/Users/Name/.gradle/caches/modules-2/org.jfrog.example.gradle/gradle-example-ci-server/1.0*) and it is present there. Below is my build.gradle code. Advise what I am missing here.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

targetCompatibility = 10
sourceCompatibility = 10

eclipse {
    classpath {
        downloadSources = true
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        credentials {
            username = "${gradleUser}"
            password = "${gradlePassword}"
        }
        url "https://leranartifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory/default-maven-local/"
        authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile(group: 'org.jfrog.example.gradle', name: 'gradle-example-ci-server', version: '1.0')
    }
}
```

JFrog Repo Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `dependencies` clause should not be in the `repositories` clause. Try to move it out:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        credentials {
            username = "${gradleUser}"
            password = "${gradlePassword}"
        }
        url "https://leranartifactory.jfrog.io/artifactory/default-maven-local/"
        authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile(group: 'org.jfrog.example.gradle', name: 'gradle-example-ci-server', version: '1.0')
}
```

Comment: I have moved the dependencies clause outside of the repositories clause but still, JARs are not added to the Project and External Dependencies. Doing Gradle refresh is displaying the below output in the console. Please advise. ------


Could not resolve: org.jfrog.example.gradle:gradle-example-ci-server:1.0
> Task :nothing UP-TO-DATE
Could not resolve: org.jfrog.example.gradle:gradle-example-ci-server:1.0

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 8s

Comment: Do you have gradle-example-ci-server in the default-maven-local repository? Look at this path: `default-maven-local/org/jfrog/example/gradle/gradle-example-ci-server`

Comment: Yes, the gradle-example-ci-server.1.0.jar is on the correct path. I have attached the JFrog repo screenshot to the main question for reference. Look into it and advise I am missing something ??